# IIR-filter implementation on a DSPIC

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, mplab, dspic

I am implementing a digital filter on a dsPIC using the dsplib library, dsPIC30F DSP Library.

I have designed my filter using MATLAB.

```
clc; clear all;
filter=designfilt('lowpassiir', 'FilterOrder', 4, 'PassbandFrequency', 3900, 'PassbandRipple', 1, 'SampleRate', 16000);
hd = dfilt.df2tsos(filter.Coefficients);

coef = fi(hd.sosMatrix)

fvtool(coef)

coef = 

    0.3949    0.7897    0.3949    1.0000   -0.0807    0.7538
    0.1279    0.2559    0.1279    1.0000   -0.7783    0.3203
```

From matlab dofumentation:

```
 SOS = [ b01 b11 b21  1 a11 a21
         b02 b12 b22  1 a12 a22
         ...
         b0L b1L b2L  1 a1L a2L ]
```

From the datasheet: There are 5 coefficients per second order (biquadratic) section arranged in the ordered set {b0[s], b1[s], a1[s], b2[s],a2[s]}, 0 ≤ s < S.

I have implemented my coefficients as suggested, see below

```
const float filter[10] = {0.3948975, 0.7897339, -0.0807495, 
0.3948975, 0.7538452, 0.1279297, 0.2558594, -0.77825928, 0.1279297,  
0.3203125};

const float filter_float[10] = {0.3948975, 0.7897339, -0.0807495, 
0.3948975, 0.7538452, 0.1279297, 0.2558594, -0.77825928, 0.1279297,  
0.3203125};

fractional filter[10]; // 5

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    filter[i]=Float2Fract(filter_float[i]);
}

fractional dbIr_1[2], dbIr_2[2];    // Delay-Line-Buffer I-Filte
(Segment 1 and 2)  
IIRTransposedStruct Filter; 
Filter.coeffsBase=filter;       // Sets the filtercoefficients
Filter.numSectionsLess1=1;      // Define number of sections
Filter.finalShift=0;            // Define shift of output (-1 
Filter.delayBase1=dbIr_1;       // Sets the delayline buffer
Filter.delayBase2=dbIr_2;       // --
Filter.coeffsPage=COEFFS_IN_DATA;   // Coefficient are stored in data 
IIRTransposedInit(&Filter);     // Initialize the filter

int blockLength=16;
int iyr[blockLength] = {0};

main{
    IIRTransposed (blockLength, iyl, xl, &Filter);
}
```

When I sent a 500hz signal through the filter, there is no signal left, actually, all signal gets damped to zero.

I did expect that the 500hz signal would remain almost unchanged. Did I do something wrong when designing the filter?

Comment: I have tried on the same code with this filter coefficient

const float Filter_float[10] = {0.178447, -0.422417, 0.844834, 0.250000, -0.356893, 0.178970, -0.495371, 0.495371, 0.500000, -0.178970}

I here there is sound. The signal is sampled at 16kHz.

Comment: I have tried a bit more today, it seems that there is a stability problem. I tried with different filter configurations, and either the sound was gone after 1 sec or it was very mechanic, like a overflow or such.